# use up.render to rerender a section in django using unpoly and alpinejs

Tags: django, alpine.js, unpoly

I am building an ecommerce website using Django with Alpine and Unpoly, In home page i got a list of products so its making a lot of queries which means it takes time, long story short, I got a functionality for adding product to wishlist and removing it from wishlist, for the a tag that added/removed a product to/from wishlist I added **up-follow** to not refreshing the page.
It works, but the problem is that it rerender the whole page(without refresh) which means its making the same queries again when instead I want to only rerender the AddToWishlist/RemoveFromWishlist part so the site wont be slow, this is how it looks:
[image]

This is the code that renders the a tags:

```
{% is_product_in_wishlist request product as is_in_wishlist %}
{% if is_in_wishlist %}  
  <a href="{% url 'products:remove-from-wishlist' product_id=product.id %}" id="id__{{product.id}}" class="absolute top-0 right-0 inline-block text-black transform duartion-200 rounded-full bg-white m-1 p-1 two" up-follow @click='removeFromWishlist'>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" class=""><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z"></path></svg>
  </a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'products:add-to-wishlist' product_id=product.id %}" id="id__{{product.id}}" class="absolute top-0 right-0 inline-block text-black transform duartion-200 rounded-full bg-white m-1 p-1 two" up-follow @click='addToWishlist'>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" class=""><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z"></path></svg>
  </a>
{% endif %}
```

This is the code I tried:

```
x-data="
 {
  removeFromWishlist(event) {
      const id = event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('id'); // gives the id of a tag
      up.render({ target: id, url: '/products/empty-wishlist-svg/', abort: false })
      },
  addToWishlist(event) {
      const id = event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('id'); // gives the id of a tag
      up.render({ target: id, url: '/products/wishlist-svg/', abort: false })
      }
}"
```

/products/empty-wishlist-svg/ and /products/wishlist-svg/ returns a html elements

some screenshots of code in case it didnt show formated:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need Alpine for this, you can do it using Unpoly and remove the `@click` attribute from your anchor tags.

In your view, check if you're treating an unpoly request (You can use a library like [python-unpoly](https://gitlab.com/rocketduck/python-unpoly)) and render only the HTML for the product that is being changed.

That way you'll render less html and perform less queries so it should be faster.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.up: # Unpoly request
        # render only html of the product that's being changed here
```

Don't forget to update `up-target` as well, so the correct part of the HTML is [swapped out](https://unpoly.com/a-up-follow#up-target).